# what kind of survival regression model should I use?

Tags: python, survival, cox-model, hazard

I have a data set where I have a duration and time to event column. I also have covariates. My aim is to measure the

1. effect size of the covariates(in terms of hazard ratio)

   2. calculate an interval, such that the cumulative hazard has reached a treshold, say 99% of the observations have completed/died.

I tried to use a coxPH model, but when I checked for the proportional hazard assumptions, all the covariates seemed to violate the assumption. My data looks as below.

```
group   type    hour    day_of_week day_of_month    duration    events
A        1       0       1              30           234         1
B        2       1       4              29           453         1
C        3       2       0              22           879         0
A        2      13       2              26           1200        0
A        3      23       4              1            600         1
B        3      5        6              8            650         0
C        3      1        4             12            560         1
C       1       2        2             10            450         0
B       2       4        5             29            342         1
A       2       2        2             0             890         0
A       3       4        8             4             100         1
```

I have used lifelines package in python. The distribution of my durations look as below.

[image]

And my overall survival curve looks like this

[image]

Any help is much appreciated!

Comment: A few points before I address your main question: 1) you have day_of_week==8, how is that possible? 2) For these "cyclic" time variables (day_of_week, hour, etc.), you should encode differently: https://ianlondon.github.io/blog/encoding-cyclical-features-24hour-time/

Comment: Hi sorry, that 8 is a typo

Comment: Can you retransform your variables are try again? Also, can you re-explain your second goal (2.). It's not clear to me.